# Need to get the duration of Quicktimes in Frames with varying framerates

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, desktop-application

I need to access the total frame count of a Quicktime file (and the framerate, hopefully).  I've been finding it difficult to get that information, or even information that I can form into a frame count.

I've been attempting to do this a few different ways, but with no real success.

It seems odd that Quicktime Player has access to all this terrific metadata and file information and I get nothin'!

So, to reiterate, does anyone know how to access the total frame duration, and possibly the frame count at the current playback location just as Quicktime Player does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

Just wanted to share my discovery, since I was having such a tough time finding any info on this.

This will read in a Quicktime movie, split it out into it's available tracks (video, audio, tc), and then find the video track.  Then it returns The total frames and the frame rate in an NSLog.

```
QTMovie *movieFile = [QTMovie movieWithFile:moviePath error:NULL];
NSArray *allTracks = [movieFile tracks];

for(QTTrack *track in allTracks)
{
    QTMedia *media = [track media];

    // Checks to make sure the quicktime media being inputted has a video track.
    if([[media attributeForKey:QTMediaTypeAttribute] isEqualToString:QTMediaTypeVideo])
    {
        NSNumber *samples = [media attributeForKey:QTMediaSampleCountAttribute];
        NSLog(@"Total Frames: %ld", (NSInteger)[samples integerValue]);
        NSLog(@"Frame Rate:  %@", [track attributeForKey:QTTrackTimeScaleAttribute]);
    }
}
```